# Access the custom fields of the product from a SKUInfo object within ShoppingCart

Tags: c#, e-commerce, kentico

We have custom fields and non-custom fields on a product page and thousands of products (approx. 250,000+ products). Information about a product contains things like warehouse and just attribute type information. When I look at an item in the shopping cart, I cannot access any of those custom fields.

I have tried the obvious `ShoppingCart.CartItems[0].GetValue("Warehouse")` which returns `null`. I also tried `ShoppingCart.CartItems[0].SKU.GetValue("Warehouse")` which also returns  `null`.

When I go to the Pages application and then to the product page, then to the form tab I can see all the SKU fields and my custom fields displayed.

Comment: What version and hotfix of Kentico are you running?

Comment: oops sorry 8.2, not sure on hotfix but a hot fix shouldn't add functionality

Answer (score 1):

The custom field for

> ShoppingCartItemInfo

are not available because they are stored in a different (coupled) table. For example you can have different types of products (mobile, laptop, keyboard...) in your shopping cart and the custom field **are not loaded** by default.

You can use following code to get the custom fields:

```
        string culture = "en-US";
        var tree = new TreeProvider(MembershipContext.AuthenticatedUser);

        foreach (var shoppingCartItem in ECommerceContext.CurrentShoppingCart.CartItems)
        {
            // we need to get class name of item in shopping cart
            var productWithClassName = tree.SelectNodes()
                .Where("NodeSKUID", QueryOperator.Equals, shoppingCartItem.SKUID)
                .And()
                .Where("DocumentCulture", QueryOperator.Equals, culture)
                .Take(1)
                .FirstOrDefault();

            if (productWithClassName != null)
            {
                var product = tree.SelectSingleNode(productWithClassName.NodeID, culture);

                if (product != null)
                {                        
                    var customField = product.GetStringValue("CustomField", "-");
                }
            }
        }
```

As you can see it is a little more complicated because in order for you to access custom field you need to get the node associated with the product and then you need to get coupled data of this node.

On a sidenote - Storing 250k documents in Kentico 8 is not recommended because there are actually some limitations of how large the content tree can be. As a rule of thumb it is recommended to have 100k documents in Kentico 8 + maximum of 1 000 direct child documents under a single node.

It is very likely that you might encounter performance issues with such a large base of products. If you can't restructuralize the content (= custom classes or custom tables) then be sure to use caching very aggresively.

Comment: ShoppingCartItemInfo doesn't contains custom fields, but the SKUInfo contains it. The SKUInfo is attribute od ShoppingCartItemInfo. If the fields are in the class SKU Info (like in my example) is it accessible through methods in my examples, otherwise no.

Comment: Neshi read the question, the custom fields are on the product not the SKU.  (I'm really not sure why Kentico treats them separately anyway, pretty lame) and most definitely not available from the SKU object or SKUInfo object.

Comment: Enn, why do you specify culture? products are culturally agnostic.

Comment: Enn to your comment about performance, yes performance is terrible even with a handful of products.  I'm beginning to regret my decision to use Kentico.  Looks like I can't use any of the built in product/shopping cart functionality, will have to roll my own, then use custom web parts for everything.

Comment: Hey, you can have almost as many products as you want, but they would need to be a standalone products (without page representation). This would mean that you dont store custom fields separatelly but as a part of Sku or you will link them manually to a record stored in custom class. Documents due to their nature with all the versioning,wowkflow,publishing etc can be limitting with so many products. Ps. Im specifying culture code because products can be translated and by default they act just like any other page which have culture.

Answer (score 0):

Where you wanna use it ?

If in static text or in the K# this work for me:

```
EcommerceContext.CurrentShoppingCart.ShoppingCartItems[0].SKU.CustomFieldName
```

In the c# in CMSCheckoutWebPart similar function to your works:

```
ShoppingCart.CartItems.FirstOrDefault().SKU.GetValue<string>("CustomFieldName","")
```

Comment: is this version 9 maybe, if you read my question you'll notice I mention that doesn't work already